# Too much delay in the completion of the cloud function

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

This is the cloud function that I'm using *to send notification to the shopkeepers when an order is accepted by the shipper.* **But sometimes it takes at least 20 seconds to complete and more often take more than  3 minutes.** My other cloud functions are working completely fine. Can't figure out the issue with this function.

```
exports.onChangeOfOrderStatus = functions.firestore
  .document('orders/{documentId}')
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    // Get an object with the current document value.
    // If the document does not exist, it has been deleted.
    const document = change.after.exists ? change.after.data() : null;
    // Get an object with the previous document value (for update or delete)
    const oldDocument = change.before.data();
    const newDocument = change.after.data();
    const oldStatus = oldDocument.orderStatus;
    const newStatus = newDocument.orderStatus;
    functions.logger.log(oldStatus);
    functions.logger.log('TO');
    functions.logger.log(newStatus);

    let orderPassed = false;
    let shopsIds = [];
    Array.prototype.push.apply(shopsIds, newDocument.shopsWhoGotOrders);
    functions.logger.log("Printing shopIds 1st time");
    shopsIds = getUnique(shopsIds);
    printArray(shopsIds); //Code works fine and instantly at this point  of line
    let shopTokensAre = [];
    if (oldStatus == 'prepending' && newStatus == 'pending') {

      shopsIds.forEach(async result => {

        await admin.firestore().collection("users")
          .where('role', "==", 'shopkeeper')
          .where('uid', '==', result)
          .get().then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(async doc => {
              shopTokensAre.push(doc.data().token);
              functions.logger.log("Printing shopIds: 2nd time"); // This line 
              //takes time to print
              functions.logger.log(doc.data().token);
              await admin.messaging().send({
                  token: doc.data().token,
                  notification: {
                    title: "Hi TELLOO Shopkeeper",
                    body: 'You received a new order, Please Accept/Reject it fastly',
                    imageUrl: 'https://support.kraken.com/hc/article_attachments/360085484571/ProApp_NewOrderButton_02082021.png',
                  }
                })
                .then(snapshot => {
                  functions.logger.log("Notifications sent");
                });
            });
          });
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the problem with specific arguments or does it happen regardless?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest reviewing the [Tips & Tricks](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips) guide for Cloud Functions to check the recommendations and avoid issues when using Cloud Functions.

> Several of the recommendations in this document center on what is known as a *cold start*. Functions are stateless, and the execution environment is often initialized from scratch, which is called a cold start.

From the issue you're describing, it is most likely that it could be a cold start issue. You could check the minimum instances configured for your function.

> By default, Cloud Functions scales the number of instances based on the number of incoming requests. You can change this default behavior by setting a minimum number of instances that Cloud Functions must keep ready to serve requests. Setting a minimum number of instances reduces cold starts of your application.

You can [set a minimum instance limit for existing functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/min-instances#setting_minimum_instance_limits), by following these steps:

> 1. Go to the Cloud Functions page in the Google Cloud Console:
>    [Go to the Cloud Functions page](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions)
> 2. Click the name of an existing function to be taken to its  **Function details**  page.
> 3. Click  **Edit**.
> 4. Click  **Runtime, build, and connection settings**  to expand additional options.
> 5. In the  **Minimum instances**  field in the  **Autoscaling**  section, enter a number greater than or equal to 1.
> 6. Click  **Next**.
> 7. Click  **Deploy**.

Additionally, you could check the [dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#use_dependencies_wisely) you use in your function:

> Because functions are stateless, the execution environment is often initialized from scratch (during what is known as a  *cold start*). When a cold start occurs, the global context of the function is evaluated.
>
> If your functions import modules, the load time for those modules can add to the invocation latency during a cold start. You can reduce this latency and the time needed to deploy your function, by loading dependencies correctly and not loading dependencies your function doesn't use.

See also:

- [Minimizing cold start time (Firecasts)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3eG9xpzNXM)

Comment: Setting minimum limit for my function to 1 and maximum to 60 didn't solve my problem in google cloud console.

Comment: Please take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71709435/13171940)

Answer (score 1):

As I see, your code it runs well until you have to query the data and do some process on it.

Nested `.forEach` are making your code slower, so it could be a good idea to change them with `for()` loops, as pointed [here](https://coderwall.com/p/kvzbpa/don-t-use-array-foreach-use-for-instead).

> `Array.ForEach` is about 95% slower than `for()`

Also, you should use [Javascript promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to terminate your function properly, as stated in the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions):

> By terminating functions correctly, you can avoid excessive charges from functions that run for too long or loop infinitely.
> ...
> Use these recommended approaches to manage the lifecycle of your functions:
>
> - Resolve functions that perform  **asynchronous**  processing (also known as "background functions") by returning a  JavaScript promise

See also:

- [Why is my Cloud Firestore query slow?](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-cloud-firestore-query-slow-e081fb8e55dd)
- [The Firebase Blog: Keeping our Promises (and Callbacks)](https://firebase.blog/posts/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76)

Answer (score 0):

You may see better performance avoiding the `async forEach` function. I've observed a similar slowness to what you've described when a Cloud Function gets overloaded.

```js
exports.onChangeOfOrderStatus = functions.firestore
  .document('orders/{documentId}')
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    const oldDocument = change.before.data();
    const newDocument = change.after.data();

    const oldStatus = oldDocument.orderStatus;
    const newStatus = newDocument.orderStatus;

    if (oldStatus !== 'prepending' || newStatus !== 'pending') {
      return;
    }

    let shopsIds = [];
    Array.prototype.push.apply(shopsIds, newDocument.shopsWhoGotOrders);

    shopsIds = getUnique(shopsIds);

    const messagingPromises = [];

    for (const shopsId of shopsIds) {
      const querySnapshot = await admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .where('role', '==', 'shopkeeper')
        .where('uid', '==', shopsId)
        .get();

      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const messagingPromise = admin.messaging().send({
          token: doc.data().token,
          notification: {
            title: 'Hi TELLOO Shopkeeper',
            body: 'You received a new order, Please Accept/Reject it fastly',
            imageUrl:
              'https://support.kraken.com/hc/article_attachments/360085484571/ProApp_NewOrderButton_02082021.png',
          },
        });

        messagingPromises.push(messagingPromise);
      });
    }

    await Promise.all(messagingPromises);
  });
```