# using firebase-admin/firestore in Cloud Function takes long time

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I use `cloud function` and `firestore` to build REST api. it used to work as expected. but it behaved weird since yesterday: all the functions execute for 1 minute and error with 'timeout'. the weird thing is I didn't do any changes to the source of my functions.

I start debugging and I find that every intercations with firestore stuck for a long time. I deploy a new function to test.

Here's the code:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.test = functions.region("asia-east1").https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log('function started---');

        const getFloors = await db.collection('floors').get();
        if (getFloors.empty) return res.send([]);

        console.log('check getFloors---');
        console.log(getFloors.docs.map(floor => floor.data()));

        return res.send(getFloors.docs.map(floor => floor.data()));
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).send(`error :${err}`);
    }
})
```

This is just a simple `get()` with firestore. To make sure there's no incorrect logic in my code, I wrap it with `try{}catch{}`. And here's the log after I call this function:

[image]

As you can see,I called this function at **12:36:06**, then it wrote `function started---` at **12:36:09**. And then function finished with 'error' after 1 minute at **12:37:06**. Finally the firestore `get()` responsed at **12:38:37**. The `await db...get()` takes 2.5 mins.

I have no idea why it takes such a long time with just a simple get. Can someone give me some advices? thx!

Comment: You don’t need to return `res.send()`. Do you see any change if you just do `res.send(getFloors.docs.map(floor => floor.data()));` instead of `return res.send()`. Apart this point your code looks perfectly good.

Comment: In your current code there is no reason to return `res.send()`. Calling `res.send()` is (with `res.redirect()` or `res.end()`) THE way to terminate the Cloud Function. Since you call it after all the asynchronous work it is totally correct.

Comment: No. it hits the same problem with or without ```return```.  BTW, is it unrecommended to use early return pattern in cloud function? I use early return to catch the expected error.

Comment: See my above comment

Comment: Thx for your response. not sure why it is not working again now...

Comment: can you check the suggestions in this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71620298/too-much-delay-in-the-completion-of-the-cloud-function) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68955793/firebase-cloud-function-taking-too-much-time-to-update-database)

Comment: has read that and seems not the same as my problem. I'm wondering if it's Cloud Function's issue.  Today I deploy same code to Google Cloud Run and it works so well. but run very slow on Cloud Function

Comment: or maybe it's because I deploy the whole **express app** that contains all the logics of api to a single cloud function endpoint? will this be a problem?

Comment: the default timeout is 60 seconds can you try to  manually extend the timeout of a Function

Comment: Have you managed to check the above comment

Comment: sorry for the late reply. the function can successfully reply if I manually set the timeout. but it's not what I want because the function shouldn't take that much time. it seems like the firestore operation take too much time abnormally.

Comment: I do nothing but only delete and redeploy this function and it works today. still not sure where goes wrong..